# „InternalServerError“ within UiPath Self-hosted Orchestrator

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-robot, uipath-orchestrator

anyone of you using self-hosted orchestrator in 2020 LTS version who has ever experienced an „InternalServerError“ WITHOUT any proper error code INSIDE UiPath Studio when starting a process from there?

UiPath Studio runs on a virtual desktop and is connected to the Self-hosted orchestrator.
The developer is developing inside UiPath Studio, starts the Process from within there for test-purposes, and receives an „InternalServerError“ without error code.

The error happens when the process needs to request something from orchestrator. Most often when using „getAssets“ or „getQueueItem“.

The workaround is to log out of the session and login again.

The error happens periodically and indecent of which Virtual Desktop is used.

Additionally, the error happens for some users, but does not happen for other users. But I can’t confirm a logic here.

Looking through logs does not give me any request errors or connection issues, the only thing I always noticed is, that the IdentityServer logs many messages regarding sessions.
So my first thought on that was, that the „UserSession“ could be terminated. When then the process is run, getAssets cannot get anything from orchestrator as the „user“ is not authenticated.

Then the very general “InternalServerError” happens because the user from within UiPath Studio is not authenticated to get something from orchestrator in that moment.

The very general InternalServerError, because orchestrator does not handle that special case..

That are my thoughts.

Anyone here who experienced similar awkward behaviours?

Many Greets,
Franz

Comment: I'd be checking Orchestrator for the machine heartbeats (the messages between Orchestrator and the remote machine) which keep the connection "alive".  It's possible that your network is dropping some, resulting in the connection going stale and disconnecting.  Is the issue resolved by selecting Refresh Connection from the lower status bar, or do you have to completely log off the box and back on?

Comment: Hmm. I also thought about connection issues already. Refreshing the connection does not solve the issue. A log off and log in is needed. My guess is that the user session could be terminated in that “not connected” state, and then a log off is needed.. but orchestrator logs do not tell any helpful information..